# JavaScript offline progress saving

Tags: javascript, objective-c, app-store

I have been working on making a game with JavaScript. When I'm done with it, I am planning on submitting to the App Store. I was going to do this by using objective C to package all the files.  (There is a tutorial on this not sure exactly what it means) I am wondering if I will be able to have an offline MySQL table to save the users progress in the game. Is it possible to have an offline MySQL table or another way to save the users progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can use cookies, `localStorage`, or `sessionStorage`. In your project I would recommend using `localStorage`. However I am not sure, because you are using JavaScript for an iOs project, that this ressource would be available. Either try or check the documentation.

[Here's the W3 Schools doc for `localStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot about local storage. I will give it a shot.